# Why SaveChanges() method takes so long in my case?

Tags: entity-framework

We use Microsoft Entity Framework Code First approach in our WPF application.

Here's the code:

```
int mainResult = base.SaveChanges();

foreach (var action in userActionsToTrack)
{
    var guid = action.EntityGuid;
    ITrackableEntity entity;
    if (addedEntities.TryGetValue(guid, out entity))
        action.EntityId = entity.Id;

    Entry(action).State = EntityState.Added;
}

base.SaveChanges();
```

First call takes about 1 second, and second one several minutes.

The base is - DbContext class.

Why is this happening?

Comment: How many actions does `userActionsToTrack` have?

Comment: More than 6000.

Comment: Try `context.Database.Log = Console.Write; ` to write your query in console, maybe you'll see something strange in the query that is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off change tracking before you perform your operations. This will improve your performance significantly (magnitudes of order). Performing your SaveChanges() outside your loop will also save you plenty of time

```
using (var context = new yourcontext())
{
    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

    //your foreach loop

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

See [this](https://ilmatte.wordpress.com/2013/01/01/entity-framework-code-first-always-disable-autodetectchanges-when-importing-data/) page for some more information. I hope it helps, otherwise let me know